# PHP Newline after curly braces

Tags: php

I have a some *.css like this :

```
.navigation-bar{color:#eee;background-color:#5e5e5e;}.nav-brand{}.nav-description{}
```

It's look so ragged, And think i can fix the code to be like this with PHP :

```
.navigation-bar{color:#eee;background-color:#5e5e5e;}
.nav-brand{}
.nav-description{}
```

After the curly braces } that will be + \n in PHP when it post on some form. What should i do ?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: can you please paraphrase, still unclear, and there is no PHP going in here only CSS

Comment: What do you know about `str_replace`?

Comment: how was the css generated? can't you just press the enter key?

Comment: Sorry, I forget str_replace. Hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$css = '.navigation-bar{color:#eee;background-color:#5e5e5e;}.nav-brand{}.nav-description{}';
$css = str_replace('}', "}\n", $css);

echo $css;
// .navigation-bar{color:#eee;background-color:#5e5e5e;}
// .nav-brand{}
// .nav-description{}
```

Note that you must include `\n` in double quotes otherwise it will be parsed literally instead of as a newline.

Comment: Of course..if you have a text editor and access to the `*.css` files, you can always just do a find & replace of this exact match (`}` to `}\n`).

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the double quotes, that solved my issue (almost a year and a half later!)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty self explanatory what this will do:

```
str_replace("}","}\n",$css)
```